# Joomla! 3.xx *onUserLogout* event not working

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I have successfully implemented the `onUserAuthenticate` event to implement my custom authentication API inside the Joomla! site that I am working on.

Now I want to also have some custom code run on the `onUserLogout` event.

I have added the following code to the custom authentication plugin file.
But this method is not getting fired/invoked while the previous one(`onUserAuthenticate`) is working just fine.

```
/**
 * Method to handle the SSO logout
 *
 * @param   array  $user     Holds the user data.
 * @param   array  $options  Array holding options (client, ...).
 *
 * @return  boolean  Always returns true.
 *
 * @since   1.6
 */
public function onUserLogout($user, $options = array()) {
    if (JFactory::getApplication()->isSite()) {
        // Set the cookie to expired date.
        setcookie('customAuth', '123', time() - (60 * 60 * 24 * 365), '/', '.customdomain.org');
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I was getting it all wrong.

So I was adding the aforementioned method inside the same plugin file that handled the `onUserAuthenticate`.

For Joomla! the login is a separate process which has its respective events like `onUserAuthenticate`.

But it seems like the event `onUserLogout` has to be inside the plugin with the `type` of `user`.

So I created a separate plugin inside the `user` plugin type directory, installed it, and enabled it....And voila!! it worked.

This had me scratching my head for quite a while.